# How can I effectively use views for a complex MySQL database for use in a CRUD?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, stored-procedures, view, crud

I am constructing a MySQL Database with the end goal of creating a GUI CRUD frontend in Microsoft Access. In the attached picture is the layout for the contacts section of this database. [[Current table relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUR7s.png)]

Ideally, all of the tables in this screenshot (barring payments) would be populated in one Access form, but I'm having trouble working out a way to make this happen. The most obvious answer (with my limited SQL knowledge) is to create a massive view connecting all of these tables, and then have the Access form call a stored procedure (either one massive SP, or one for each field? Not clear on this) to C/R/U/D the view.

I tested out creating a view with a few tables (one many-to-many relationship and one one-to-many) below:

```
CREATE 
ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
DEFINER = lauren3@% 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW peopleformview AS
SELECT 
    p.PersonID AS personid,
    p.Title AS title,
    p.FirstName AS firstname,
    p.LastName AS lastname,
    p.Role AS role,
    p.DOB AS dob,
    p.PassportNum AS passportnum,
    p.Alumni AS alumni,
    p.Degree AS degree,
    p.Nickname AS nickname,
    p.Email AS email,
    p.PermissiontoEmail AS permissiontoemail,
    ar.agent AS agent,
    a.AddressID AS AddressID,
    a.Address1 AS Address1,
    a.Address2 AS Address2,
    a.City AS City,
    a.State_Province AS State_Province,
    a.PostCode AS PostCode,
    a.Country AS Country
FROM
    (((people p
    LEFT JOIN agentref ar ON ((p.agentref_agentid = ar.agentid)))
    LEFT JOIN people_has_addresses pha ON ((pha.people_PersonID = p.PersonID)))
    LEFT JOIN addresses a ON ((pha.addresses_AddressID = a.AddressID)))
```

Am I on the right track here? It seems that such a view would get unweidly quickly.

Comment: Typically, in Access, you don't use queries/SPs at all for CRUD, and represent relationships using subforms. It's not clear to me at all what you're trying to accomplish with this stored procedure.

Comment: The intent of the view is to bring together this information in a way that can be displayed/edited in an Access form, but I realize that such data can't be shown in a single row of a query/view due to the nature of the relational database. What, then, is the best way to pull the information shown in the image into a single Access form? You mention using subforms, but to my understanding subforms require Access to recognize relationships between tables, which it won't do because it's linked with an ODBC connection. Should I manually re-add the relationships in the Access relationship editor?

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. You can link subforms together as you wish without the need for relationships. It's just that they auto-link if you do have a relationship, but you can link them manually as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be it the desktop, the web or just about any platform?

You model and display and edit relational data by cobbling together parts that are based on the relationships.

But, you actually base each part directly on a single table. You don’t create a view server side to join all that data together. And you don't use SQL either.

If you have one customer, and 30 invoices, then if you join the tables, then the customer will appear 30 times. You can’t possible edit such a mess as one data row.

So this would be the related tables:
[image]

So, in the case of access, you would build a form that edits the main customer. Such a form lets you edit one customer at a time. Build that one form – get it working all nice.

[image]
Again, above is based on one linked table.

Now, to display the invoices for the one customer? Ok, now build a new form (multiple items form). And you base this form on the invoices table.

[image]

Once you build the two forms? Well, open up your main customer form in design mode, and now simply drag + drop in the invoices form from the nave pane.

So, you wind up with a screen like this:

[image]

You can see the main form has things like customer name, address etc.

And the other form (a sub form) shows the list of invoices you have for this one customer.

The beauty of Access is it will connect up the main form, and the sub form for you, and do so without code. So, each main customer record you navigate to will now show the child related records in that sub form. You do this by setting the link master and child settings in the sub form control:

[image]

Now, of course each invoice will have a “main” invoice part. (Date, customer, maybe billing address). And for each invoice, you will have a child table of invoice details. (Quantity, item, price amount etc. for each thing in that one invoice). So once again, the above simple concept is repeated for this invoice form, and the child form of “invoice details”.

So, in above when I click on an invoice, we simply open up a main invoice form to the ONE invoice record, and the child invoice details is again displayed as a sub form. Like this:

[image]

So, be this desktop development, or even web development?

You create a user interface based on dropping parts into a form that are each based on a single table.

So each part that displays records as a general rule will be based on a SINGLE table. You thus as a result for such data editing will NEVER use a view or data joined together for editing.

And with Access you not use any sql either.

Each bit and part you used to edit data will be directly based on ONE single linked table in access and not some view.

As a result, you don’t need views, and you don’t even need sql for each part you build.

The ability  to edit relational data will thus be based on how you cobble together each bit and part, but each of those parts are NOT going to be based on some sql query, and in fact not based on a view either. Each of the parts you use will be based directly on a linked table, and a single table at that.

Each part you use here ONLY ever edits ONE record at time. Read that last sentence 10 times to ensure you grasp this simple rule.

So, you can certainly get creative. So, here is an example form that shows 3 tables all at the same time. IN this example, we have an event, a then people and their donation for the event. And we need to split out the donation into different accounts. Someone might give $50, but 10 is for funerals, and the other $40 might be for the school.

[image]

The top part is the donation event (one record). ON the left side is a continues form that shows the people that donated to the event, and their amount. And on the right side we show the accounts for a single donation we selected on the left side. Each donation can be split out into multiple accounts.

This is a common and “classic” accounting type screen in which you enter a given amount, but split it out and apply it into multiple accounts.

And again, the above Access form is not based on views or even sql queries, but each part we placed into the form is based a single linked table.

So it is the slicing and dicing of bits and parts that you place into a form that allows and gives you the ability to edit related data, but each part is only based on a single table out of your elated data model.

It is “how” you cobble together these bits and parts that allows the magic of editing of related data. As such, this process and thinking on your part has really very little to do with building views that join together related data. In all of the above examples, I did not write any sql or create any views, and each part was simply based directly on a linked table, and not even some sql. So your related data model is a “guide” and will give you information as to what table and part comes next in building your user interface.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed write up! My only question comes from the fact that in my effort to follow best practices for relational database construction, I've split out my data considerably, with several connected many-to-many relationships for the contacts section alone (pictured above). For example, since one person can have multiple addresses on file, and one address could be used for multiple people, I have that set up as M to M. Because of that, it seems my contacts entry form would get very complex, very quickly. Is this the norm for relational DB frontends, or am I missing something?

Comment: Not really. Take a look at the 2nd to last screen shot. It shows a  invoice form and note the address display. That address display is a sub form. so in the main invoice form you could have a combo box to select the address, or even a sub form to edit the address.  so a sub form was used on the form to display the address. In my case one address, but it is a sub form that can display many address. Sub form does not have to be a continues form. So may well have to use query/view to join in the address fields for display. So in some cases, yes you can and will use sql joins for display of data.

Comment: I used a sub form to display the address in the invoice form, I don't allow editing. So I was pushing the point that bits and parts you add to a form are based on one table because that is usually required for editing. However, the address example above was not for editing,but only for display of the address and I sill used a sub form. So in some cases, yes that sub form could and would be a sql query/view, but then I am NOT talking about editing of data anymore, but using a form for display of data. That rule about "always" basing a sub form direct to a table was in context of editing data.

Comment: If you building somthing to display some related parts, but more for selecting that data part, then some of those sub forms or combo boxes will most certainly be based on sql that joins tables, but the general rule is that you still using those sub form parts to display related data, and for the most part the main form still going to be based on a single table. But some of the parts you need and drop into a form to display related data will be and could be a sql join, but just for that part you drop in.